# T&T as a parameter in C# from query

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to get a parameter T&T to api  by angular .from angular T&T sending as a parameter but .net core api site it is divided and T only taking as parameter .Could you please anyone tell me how to pack T&T as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Using the `&` in the query string, we could add multiple parameters. If you want to send a parameter value which contains the `&` character, you have to Encode the it using the encodeURIComponent() function, then the `&` character will be changed to `%26`. More detail information, see [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

So, try to replace the `&` to `%26`.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

[image]